# Loop a TextWatcher?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, textwatcher

I am currently trying to make an app similar to Type To Learn (I know it really has no purpose since it's on a phone but I'm just doing it for fun). Basically I have a text file full of words that I've split into an arraylist and I am trying to use each element in that arraylist as something that the user has to type. This is my code right now:

```
final EditText answerText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.word);
    final ArrayList updatedList = helperMethod();
    String response = "";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < updatedList.size();i++)
    {
        final String word = updatedList.get(i).toString();
        text.setText("Please type the word: " + word);
    final TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() 
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            ArrayList updatedList = helperMethod();
            String answer = s.toString();
            if(answer.equals(word))
            {
                 text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                 answerText.setText("");
            }
        }           
        public void  beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }
        public void  onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) 
        {

        }
    };
```

I am trying to use a TextWatch for each element, and after the element is correctly typed, have it go on to the next element of the arraylist through the for-loop. Unfortunately ,this is only displaying the last element of the arraylist. Is it not possible to loop through a TextWatch?

Please let me know if you need more information/code/etc.

Thanks!!

Comment: Need more clarity on hat you really wanted to achieve. You are creating the textwatcher instance but not attaching to the target TextView.

Comment: Basically if the ArrayList is {Hey, My, Name, Is, Joe} I want it to be like "Please type Hey" and then if the user types in "Hey", the TextView should change to "Please type My" and so on...